# Has anyone used C++ REST SDK (Codename "Casablanca")? For an HTTP CLIENT?

Tags: c++, http, networking

I've been looking around at different libraries to make a HTTP client.

Boost::asio

LibCurl

netLib

Chilkat

From what I've seen Casablanca seems the easiest to use and overall looks pretty good.

Can someone explain to me why someone would be these options over Casablanca?